# Dual Boot with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

This is a cross post from the [Linux forum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290844/dual-boot-windows-10-with-ubuntu) that maybe people can help me with

I bought a new SSD and attempted to install elementary OS on it. When i reset the PC i do not get the option of booting into Elementary OS

As a work around (based on the answe i am able to hit f2 and set the boot order to boot into the system but then i don't have access to windows

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run the LiveCD, or boot from USB again (whichever you did to install it). select the "Try elementary OS" option, Then in that session, connect to the internet and install boot repair.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Do the recommended fix, to install Grub on your System. When grub is installed, feel free to reboot. When you reboot you should be brought to a page similar to this. [image]

There should be an option relating to windows (maybe multiple). Just try them all out (if there are multiple), and see which one boots you into Windows.

(Optional) When you figure it out, reboot back into Elementary OS,install Grub customizer

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`

and find the option that booted you into Windows, and then rename to to Windows (preferably), then hit save in the upper top left corner!